# How can I enable CAS Dashboard ("/status/dashboard" endpoint)

Tags: c#, asp.net, maven, gradle, cas

I am trying to customize my current CAS WAR Overlay. More specifically I need to get access to Dashboard (or something where I could do some changes, maybe change default user password atleast).
CAS documentation is a great source, but I found out that it's quite overwhelming for beginner, especially if you did not used spring boot before.

So far I made a fresh install of CAS version 5.2 with Gradle, and deployed .war file on Tomcat 9.0 localhost. SSL is enabled. Note: Part with Gradle and Maven dependencies is clear.

Currently I am only able to login with casuser//Mellon default credentials. And I can see the links to things like Dashboard and such... But when I try to navigate there, I am told that I need permission to view that page.
Bellow is content of cas.properties file located:

```
[cas-overlay-root]/etc/cas/config/cas.properties
```

So far that is the only thing that I edited.

```
    # server.port = 8443
    cas.server.name: https://localhost:8443
    cas.server.prefix: https://localhost:8443/cas
    cas.adminPagesSecurity.ip=127\.0\.0\.1
    logging.config: file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
    # cas.serviceRegistry.config.location: classpath:/services
    # SSL
    # server.ssl.enabled=false
    server.ssl.enabled=true
    server.ssl.keyStore=file:/etc/cas/thekeystore
    server.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
    server.ssl.keyPassword=changeit
    server.port=8443
```

Any information on how to customize CAS Web Overlay, and enable links would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe some other people will find this useful, so these are the settings which worked for me. They are very useful for testing local configuration because they are not secured so they should not be used in production.

```
    endpoints.enabled = true
    endpoints.sensitive = false
    endpoints.actuator.enabled = true
    management.security.enabled = false
    cas.adminPagesSecurity.ip = 127\\.0\\.0\\.1
    cas.adminPagesSecurity.actuatorEndpointsEnabled = true
    cas.monitor.endpoints.enabled = true
    cas.monitor.endpoints.sensitive = false
```

Please note that the ip property is a regular expression.

Comment: Hi Virgium, Thanks for reply, that worked perfect;y. I added this information into [Tomcat]/webapps/[cas folder]/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties and restarted the Tomcat service. This is not intended for production.